# NullPointerException Difficulty

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So I'm having some trouble with a programming assignment. I have created the class required, and it has compiled fully, but when I run it, i get a NullPointerException.

All of the exceptions point back to this method;

```
public void initializeCount(){
for(int j=0; j<t.length; j++){
 String s=t[j];
 WordCount h=new WordCount(s);
 xx[j]=h;
}
}
```

xx[] is an array of pertinent objects (WordCount), and is defined in the beginning of the class (I can't remember what this is called, still new to programming)

```
public class WordFreq extends Echo{
  private String wordString;
  private String[] t;
  private WordCount[] xx;
  private int words=0;
  Scanner scan;
 }
```

t is an array of string objects, which is filled in the constructor

```
public WordFreq (String x, String y) throws IOException{
super(x);
wordString=y;
t=wordString.split(" ");
scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
}
```

Back to the initializeCount method, what I want it to do is take the words held in t[], turn them into WordCount objects, then put those objects in xx[].

Edit: I'm pretty sure I initialized xx at the beginning of the class, I could be wrong though:

```
public class WordFreq extends Echo{
private String wordString;
private String[] t;
private WordCount[] xx;
private int words=0;
Scanner scan;
}
```

If anyone could explain to me why the initializeCount method is causing a NullPointerException, I should be able to fix it and get the program working properly. Any help is greatly appreciated, and I can provide more of the program's code if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Is the xx array initialized somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I think I did in the beginning of the problem

Comment: `public class WordFreq extends Echo{
  private String wordString;
  private String[] t;
  private WordCount[] xx;
  private int words=0;`
  Scanner scan;

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize xx I think you want xx to be initialized to the size of t, so do something like

```
  xx = new WordCount[t.length];
```

Comment: Actually, I think I initialized xx in the beginning `public class WordFreq extends Echo{
  private String wordString;
  private String[] t;
  private WordCount[] xx;
  private int words=0;
  Scanner scan;`

Comment: is that the code that you 'initialized' with? because that isn't an initializing statement, that is just declaration, after `t=wordString.split(" ");` just put `xx = new WordCount[t.length];`

Answer (score 0):

Did object 't' is initialized somewhere

Can you change your initialize method as below and check what is printing for object t. I suspect object t is null. I added a null check also to prevent null pointer exception.

```
public void initializeCount(){
System.out.println("What is the value of t --->"+t);
if(t!= null){
for(int j=0; j<t.length; j++){
 String s=t[j];
 WordCount h=new WordCount(s);
 xx[j]=h;
}
}
}
```